# Getting index of virtual field using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, virtual-field

Im using QGIS 3.18.2 and I want to get the expression string of a virtual field in `PyQGIS`.

`QgsVectorLayer.expressionField()` is supposed to return the expression string. It takes the index (`index: int`) of the expression (virtual) field as argument.

Let's say I have a virtual field named `expr_f_1`. When I call  `QgsVectorDataProvider.fieldNameIndex("expr_f_1")` it returns `-1`, which corresponds to a missing field. This seems to happen for virtual fields in general.
They also don't appear in `QgsVectorDataProvider.fieldNameMap()`.

How do I get the correct index of a virtual field, in order to pass it to  `QgsVectorLayer.expressionField()` to return the corresponding expression string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `layer.fields().indexFromName("expr_f_1")`.

Because:

> Virtual fields are a pure QGIS concept. The data provider does not know the slightest bit about their existence. Virtual fields are just put "on top of" the real data, their values are temporarily regenerated by QGIS every time they are required somewhere.

You may want to read [Matthias's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/167148/29431) for more information.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
i = layer.fields().indexFromName("expr_f_1")
print(layer.expressionField(i))
```